# Can I get qmake -project to add LIBS += .... to my .pro file?

Tags: qt, project, qmake

I have a project that uses Qt. So I have "qmake" make my Makefile from the .pro file. But Qmake can also make that .pro file: qmake -project . This worked until I needed to add an external extra library to my project.

I get lots of hits on google that tell me to add LIBS += ... to my project file, but I want to tell qmake -project something that causes it to add it for me. In effect of course I'll be doing it myself, but I don't think that it's proper that I am editing the generated project file.

If for example I add files to the project directory, I'll have to recreate it and add in the library again, or I'll have to manually add the files to the (almost completely computer-generated) project file. I'm now using a script to auto-generate the project file, and then add in the LIBS += directive, but is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

When you are developing without the Qt Creator IDE, unless the IDE includes by itself some automatic utilities, you must edit manually the .pro configuration file.

The generated .pro file is a skeleton file which YOU must fill in with the libraries that you need, then the qmake system figures out the other dependencies and compiles your project. It is a essentially a much better version of pkg-config of gtk + Makefiles.

When you add more source and resource files to your project then manually you must add them to the .pro file.

Example:

```
QT       += core gui

TARGET = qtcp1
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
        miwidget1.cpp \
        lcdrange.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
            miwidget1.h \
            lcdrange.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.u
```

Alternately, you can issue `qmake -project` over and over again, but this can cause some unforseen accidents, since it includes everything that is in the current directory at the time, including  the pre-processed files for conversion to standard C++ from QT dialect. This intermediate files must be erased (cleaned), before the remaking the project and the next make or can lead to tricky problems.

Using the official and free QT Creator  IDE takes away most of this burden by adding automatically the new data to the .pro file and cleaning loose ends. Some other IDEs like Code::BLocks and Codelite provide some facilities for QT, but not to the level of QT creator. Some prefer to edit the  .pro themselves for custom reasons, other like more other styles of IDEs, like Eclipse.

You should test the waters and decide by yourself what fits best to your needs.

ReEdited, to clarify a few things.

Comment: That makes the short answer: "No, there is no proper way to do this".

Comment: I don't know what you define as proper, the QtCreator IDE gives you point and click facilities, add new sources files automatically, includes various code versioning tools, a built-in forms creator which also automatically adds the result to the .pro file, adding external libraries is a right click-> wizard to add libraries. I doubt there is a build system in the world that can satisfy you if this can't. You should give a more clear example of what you consider "proper".